# A solution to enable push for Inbox Messages

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, notifications, push

I'm setting up a new web app, and that webapp has a link for inbox (messages), where I could put a count like 0 or 1 if there are new messages.

The website is in Spring MVC with jsp frontend (javascript/css/html). I have looked for the desired push notifications but the ones shown on google are a different form of notifications where we ask user's permission to Allow/Block. I clearly need a different solution.

My type of requirement is similarly implemented here on stack overflows menu where we are notified of various events from the server

If my question has some issues, please inform me and I will correct it.

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907024/push-notification-for-a-web-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48466540/sending-push-notifications-from-java-web-application) but they dont answer my question

Kind Regards

Comment: there are several ways to do that, for example with sse https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events

Comment: I will check it out. Thanks much!

Comment: also may help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications